# Is PHOTOGRAPHY halal or haraam?

Tags: halal-haram

Assalamu Alaikum Warahmatullahi Wabarakatuhu
There are so many opinions and I would like to know the.answer with evidences from the Quran and Sahih Hadith.
Is Photography halal or haraam?
Jazakallah Khair.

Comment: There is obviously no direct ruling from the Quran and Hadith as it did not exist at the time of the Prophet. There is difference of opinion on Photography, we can not choose for you and give you "the" correct answer, at best we can give a description of the opinions and the evidence or reasoning they are based on.

Comment: Yeah please do that, jazakallah khair.

Answer (score -1):

As stated by UmH above there is no direct ruling from the Quran and Hadith but this is what islamqa has to say. https://www.google.com/amp/s/islamqa.info/amp/en/answers/365